# Creating asynchronous function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, function-call

Is it possible to call function in javascript and don't wait for results? I have a lot of recursive calls and they consumes a lot of memory, so I sometimes got "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: Can you show the piece of code which is causing that problem, so that we can optimize it?

Comment: You are recursing too much. And you aren't thinking in the right direction to fix the problem.

Comment: It's not a piece. I'm trying to find alternatives, so I don't do refactoring.

Comment: To expand on what @AndrewBarber said, making it asynchronous will not change the depth of the call stack.  So it won't fix the underlying problem.  There are techniques to manually optimize tail-calls.  You might want to search on "trampolining" for Javascript.

Comment: The point here is you need to refactor and fix your algorithm.  JS is single threaded so you can't take a piece of regular JS and suddently make it async.  You could explore webWorkers, but that's not going to change your memory consumption - for that you need to rethink HOW your algorithm works.

Comment: @jfriend00 async and multi-threaded is not the same thing...

Comment: When you have recursivness filling up the stack it indicates you do the calls at a too deep level. Try to refactor your calls to be spawn from parent or higher up if necessary.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg - Did I say they were the same thing?  No, I did not.

Comment: @jfriend00 did I say you said? :) I just pointed out they are not the same thing as it could be easily interpreted as such as the comment stands.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg - yes, by addressing your comment at me, you appeared to think I said that.  Anyway, async or threading aren't the OP's solution here.  They need a better algorithm for solving their issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
setTimeout( function(){ ..... }, 0  )
```

Comment: How about letting the poster determine this.   It very well might solve the problem

Comment: I'm trying to imagine any scenario where this would help except in combination with a serious refactoring of the algorithm.  Can you describe one?  But I did remove my downvote.

Comment: setTimeout() will execute and the browser will not wait for the result.  This is what was asked, "Is it possible to call function in javascript and don't wait for results?"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and not related to waiting for the function to return. The problem you are having is that you are calling a function within a function.

Once a function is called the calling function state is pushed onto the stack. If this then calls another function then the state is pushed onto the stack. The stack has to grow. You need to look at your design and whether recursion is appropriate for your problem.

If you do not need the result from a function or need to wait for it to return do you need recursion atall.